# UitableView Row selection and UIButton Action

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, tableview

I have an UitableView with five rows and a button. I managed to create the checkmark for one row i mean that the user can check only one row.When checks another row the previus one unchecked. Now can someone help on how to connect my button with the selection of row. I tried something but not working.

Here is my code in cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

and my button code :

```
if (reloadSelectedRow==1) {

   PlayViewController * controller = [[PlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayViewController" bundle:nil];
    //controller.countdownLabel.text= score;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

}

the reloadSelectedRow is an int variable that i create it .h and use it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as:

```
reloadSelectedRow = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row];
```

The problem is when i press the button nothing happens. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[YourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

You could get the pressed button's superView like this, and the index path:

```
 -(void)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{    

    //Get the superview from this button which will be our cell
    UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    NSIndexPath *pathToCell = [tableView indexPathForCell:owningCell];

}
```

Comment: incmiko can you please explain me more? I don't understand where to use the first method?

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath. - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents. With this method you can add an action to your button. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: i haven't  put a specific call for my tableview i think or i can't understand at all the implemetation.Anywhay thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For swift version.I have made multi choice answers for each row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalTestTC", for: indexPath) as! PersonalTestTC

    cell.questionTitle.text = "some question here"

    cell.choiceButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.choiceButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.choiceButton2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.choiceButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.choiceButton3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.choiceButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.choiceButton4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.choiceButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.choiceButton5.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.choiceButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.choiceButton1.tag = 1
    cell.choiceButton2.tag = 2
    cell.choiceButton3.tag = 3
    cell.choiceButton4.tag = 4
    cell.choiceButton5.tag = 5

    return cell

}
```

To get which row and which answer have been selected using tag to identify

```
func choiceButtonPress(sender: UIButton){

    let tbcell : UITableViewCell = sender.superview?.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let getCell : IndexPath = testListTable.indexPath(for: tbcell)!

    print(getCell.row)
    print(sender.tag)

}
```

For superview , It s depend on how may UIButton you are on top of it.